# Block all images in Firefox but see only those I want

Tags: images, firefox

I want to block all images in Firefox except a few I choose.

I found the [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/) add-on, but if I use that I can't see where the images were.

I prefer something like the [Show Selected Images](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/show-selected-images/) add-on (which can reload a broken image by hovering mouse the over it) that shows me where the image is.

I'm looking for an add-on that shows all images as broken and when I hover my mouse over a particular image allows me to load/view it.

It would also be OK if that add-on showed the image link instaed of the image.

Comment: Raw idea: GreaseMonkey and a UserScript that obfuscates the `<img>` "src" attribute (e.g. by adding a char to it) and restores it onMouseOver (by removing that char again). Not sure if such exists, though.